# symfony get request returns %40

Tags: php, symfony, request

I have this code:

```html
<form action="/news" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="datas" placeholder="Email" required="">
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
</form>
```

And in controller function:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

# announcing class and blabla

public function news() {
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $request->query->get('datas');
    $content = $request->getContent();
    echo $content.' ';
    if(isset($_POST['datas'])) 
        echo $_POST['datas'];
    return new Response(
        'Lucky number'
    );
}
```

So when i try to request the method it returns

```
email%40.domen
```

But when i try the standart `$_POST`m it returns

```
email@.domen
```

Whats wrong? How can i change `%40` to `@`. Of course i can manipulate with text characters but its the best approach and is not effective using the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t have to use `getContent() or ->query()` it’s enough to do `$content = $request->request->get(‘datas’);`
query is equivalent to $_GET and request is equivalent to $_POST
 see [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#accessing-request-data)